# AJAX function call after readystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I'm sending an Ajax call to a server and trying to call another function when the response is ready (readystatechanged). The serverside code is non existent at this moment.  The "another" function call fails with Chrome and Firefox. Unexpectedly, Internet Explorer 8 has no trouble calling the function.

I'm able to create the XMLHttpRequest object in Chrome and Firefox (and an ActiveXObject in IE8). I also am able to use open and send and receive readystatechanges and statuscodes. What chrome and firefox are unable to do is call the functions "drawTable()" and "drawChart()"

```
if( xhr.readystate == 4 && xhr.status == 200 )
{
  drawTable();
  drawChart();
}
```

I can traceback the execution with Firebug and Google Chrome Script tool to the above if-statement. The member variables readystate and status have the correct values. Unlike IE8, Chrome and Firefox will not simply call the functions.

Comment: 1. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). 2. Any particular reason you're not using one of the many available cross-browser frameworks? 3. It's probably a race condition problem.

Comment: can you console.out xhr before the if statement and show us what you see?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Matt. This is my first question at SO, will bookmark your SSCCE link :) By cross-browser framework you mean?

Comment: Why would he use jQuery just for this?

Comment: Forming a question to a problem seems to be healthy. This question pointed out the answer for me: a typo ( xhr.readystate -> xhr.readyState )

Comment: please, please understand that `W3Schools != W3C` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. The property is actually `readyState` (note the uppercase `S`).

Comment: Yep. Fixing the typo fixed the problem. Thanks